# replitでのサイトにgoogle広告は掲載可能ですか？

Tags: javascript, html, css

replitを使ってサイトを作っておりgoogle広告で稼ぎたいなーと思い審査してもらっているのですが、サブドメインがダメらしく目的のサイトを登録できません。

replitのサイトでgoogle広告はできるのか、またできるのであれば方法を教えてください。

Comment: このスレッドあたりが参考になるかもしれません。[Google adsense on repl.it?](https://replit.com/talk/ask/Google-adsense-on-replit/58948)

Comment: ありがとうございます！
自分の名前と同じreplを作るといいと書いてあったので一度やってみます！

Comment: プログラミングの質問というよりは、各サービスでのルールや規約を確認すべき内容であり、当サイトで扱う話題の範囲からはやや外れる気がします。